# How to import named amd's and its exports in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to import [ic-modal](https://github.com/instructure/ic-modal/blob/master/dist/named-amd/main.js) into an ember-cli project, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught Error: <ic-test@view:toplevel::ember278> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'ic-modal-trigger' on object (generated application controller).`

I have the following import statements:

`app.import('vendor/ic-styled/main.js');
app.import('vendor/ic-modal/dist/named-amd/main.js', {
  'ic-modal': [
    'ModalComponent',
    'ModalFormComponent',
    'ModalTriggerComponent',
    'ModalTitleComponent',
    'modalCss'
  ]
});`

Any help with this would be great?!

Answer (score 0):

In `Brocfile.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/ic-styled/main.js');
app.import('bower_components/ic-modal/dist/named-amd/main.js');
```

Replace `bower_components` with `vendor` in the above if you're still using an older version of Ember-CLI.

Then use:

```
import ICModal from 'ic-modal';
// Can now utilise ICModal, ICModal.ModalForm etc
```

The Broccoli build and ES6 module transpiler should take care of the rest.

(Side-note: when using Coffeescript, put the `import` statement in backticks as the standard Coffeescript compiler doesn't handle the ES6 syntax.)